# Go through Loop with a mysqli array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

i'm new to mysqli and i'm losing my mind to the array.

i'm getting this array:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#11422 (1) {
    ["ingredientes"]=>
    string(6) "Frango"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#11419 (1) {
    ["ingredientes"]=>
    string(10) "Mozzarella"
  }
  [2]=>
  object(stdClass)#11423 (1) {
    ["ingredientes"]=>
    string(5) "Caril"
  }
  [3]=>
  object(stdClass)#11420 (1) {
    ["ingredientes"]=>
    string(5) "Natas"
  }
  [4]=>
  object(stdClass)#11424 (1) {
    ["ingredientes"]=>
    string(6) "Cebola"
  }
}
```

and i want to "print" only the "Frango", "Mozarella", "Caril", etc...

i already tried:

```
 while($result_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $oresult_row['ingredientes']; 
  }
```

```
  foreach($result as $key => $ingredientes){
    echo $result[$key][];
  }
```

```
foreach($result as $key => $name){
  echo $result[$key];
}
```

```
 while ($i < count($result)) {
    echo $result[$i]->row['name'];
    $i++; 
  }
```

```
  for ($i = 0; $i < count($result); $i++ ) {
   echo $result[0][$i];
  }
```

i'm working with wordpress 
and this is who i'm getting the array:

```
  $id = $product->id;
  global $wpdb;      
  $query = "SELECT wt.name FROM wp_term_relationships wtr JOIN  wp_term_taxonomy wtt ON wtr.term_taxonomy_id = wtt.term_taxonomy_id JOIN wp_terms wt ON wt.term_id = wtt.term_id JOIN wp_posts wp ON wp.ID = wtr.object_id WHERE wp.ID =" . $id . " AND wtt.taxonomy = 'Ingrediente'";
  $result = $wpdb->get_results($query);
```

Comment: foreach($result as $key => $value){
    echo $value->ingredientes;
  }

Comment: don't work, it stay in blank

Comment: forget, yes it work, gosh thank u!!

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
foreach($result as $key => $object){
  echo $object->ingredientes;
}
```

Or

```
foreach($result as $object){
  echo $object->ingredientes;
}
```